# Hiding multiple tables based on condition child tables visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have HTML as below and it contains multiple parent tables and each parent table will have a `class` like this:

```
<table class="customFormTable block">
```

This in turn contains some child tables like this:

```
<table id="elementTableContainer(app_spec_info_POLICE_DETAILS_Police_Station)" width="80%" style="visibility: hidden;">
```

I am looking for Javascript/jQuery to scan all main tables with class  `customFormTable` and find if any children table starting with id `elementTableContainer` has  `style="visibility: hidden;"`. If so, hide that specific parent table i.e table `customFormTable`

Below is the code and it should hide second table i.e 'Police Details' and should show only first table i.e 'Amputation Details' as the second table contains child tables with visibility hidden as `<table id="elementTableContainer(app_spec_info_POLICE_DETAILS_Police_Station)" width="80%" style="visibility: hidden;">`

https://jsfiddle.net/sukumar/vq64597e/23/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through each `.customFormTable` parent table first, then check for their respective `[id^=elementTdContainer]` child tables and if they are empty, then only hide the current `$(this)` parent table, instead of hiding all parent tables:

```
$('.customFormTable').each(function() {
   if ($(this).find("[id^=elementTdContainer]").css("visibility") === "hidden") {
      $(this).hide(); //hide your parent table 
   }
});
```